# Can't figure out why my results are appearing with ListBox{"name"}

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, checkedlistbox

```
public void loadAllEmployeesFromSQLServer()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=WIN2008SERVER;Database=Kiosk;Uid=kiosk;Pwd=kiosk;";
    conn.Open();
    string query = "SELECT [displayName],[activeDirectoryName],[roleID],[activeAccount] FROM [ProbationKiosk].[dbo].[Employees]";


    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = query;

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ArrayList allEmployees = new ArrayList();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        employees emp = new employees(dr["displayName"].ToString(), dr["activeDirectoryName"].ToString(), dr["roleID"].ToString(), Int32.Parse(dr["activeAccount"].ToString()));
        allEmployees.Add(emp);

        string[] employeeData = new string[3];
        employeeData[0] = emp.commonName;
        employeeData[1] = emp.activeDirectory;
        employeeData[2] = emp.currentRole;
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(employeeData);
        if (emp.isActive == 1)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(lvi, true);
        }
        else
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(lvi, false);
        }

    }
}
```

I made my `CheckedListBox` a multicolumn table.

I debugged my code and I am getting the data stored into `ListViewItem`
but when it's being displayed to the UI, it appears as

```
"ListViewItem {"name..."}"
```

instead of

```
"[ ]     |   First Name Last Name  |    active directory name   | roleID"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing that because when you execute the following line:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add(lvi, true);
```

It's implicitly calling `lvi.ToString()`, which is displaying the name of the class.

---

Try this instead:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add(string.Join(" | ",
    lvi.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>().Select(x => x.Text)));
```

---

Also, I assume you're setting the `MultiColumn` property on the `CheckedListBox` to `true`. That does not lay things out nicely formatted, like in a grid. It just determines whether or not items display in a single column or flow into multiple columns as space permits.

`MultiColumn = false`:

[image]

`MultiColumn = true`:

[image]

You might be able to attain a quasi-table layout by using tabs, but it may look funny if some strings are much longer than the rest.

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add(string.Join("\t",
    lvi.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>().Select(x => x.Text)));
```

You could probably get around that by finding the longest probable string and padding the `Text` property accordingly:

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add(string.Join("",
    lvi.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                .Select(x => x.Text.Padding(20, ' ')));
```

Comment: Sorry. The vertical delimiter was suppose to represent a new column in my listbox. I did the checkedListBox1.Items.Add(lvi, true); because it sets the checkbox to  checked or unchecked (based on the value from the database.

Comment: I updated my code to say checkedListBox1.Items.Add(lvi.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>().Select(x => x.Text), false); and now i get System.Linq.Enumeration